# HDMI: Can a computer still detect a monitor properly if some of the TDMS pins/wires are damaged?

Tags: cables, hardware, computers, hdmi, monitor

Can a faulty HDMI-cable with damaged TDMS pins/wires still work to the extent that the computer can still detect the monitor, but the monitor just will not display anything (except for no signal)?

Comment: Yes. Monitor identification is carried out through the DDC pins - an I2C interface separate from the display data channels.

Comment: Not sure what you expect from this question except get and test with a spare or new cable.

Comment: @SolarMike I just wanted to know, if it's technically possible. I.e., if the standard allows this kind of "partial function" which might give the impression that the cable is ok, while it actually is not.

Of course I could just buy new cables every time the problem re-appears, but it would not help to identify the actual root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI sources use the DDC (I2C) channel to identify the monitor and its capabilities. So, yes, the source could identify the sink if TMDS were broken.

But it won’t be able to do HDCP since keying material is sent in-band over TMDS and managed by DDC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If monitor can detect 5V from PC, monitor will assert hotplug. If PC can detect monitor hotplug, PC knows monitor is connected tries to read EDID. If EDID can be read, PC knows monitor is connected and the information it has. The monitor does not have to be turned on or have any power to make this happen, and the PC knows from the TMDS lines if the monitor is ready to accept video or not.